# how to create a Textformfield with the ability to place images?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eggad.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKDGM.png)

What I need to create in a specific way is a floatingbutton in which it goes to an addpage, where there will be a textformfield. I want to know how to put images from the gallery in the course of the text, in the middle, has as? If anyone can give me a tip I appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like an inline/HTML Editor to achieve that interface.
You can do it in two ways:

1. Using an HTML editor

You can use this library [HTML Editor](https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor)

2. Else you can use an inline rich text editor like
   [Zefyr](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr)

Both these solutions would work equally fine.

Comment: Zefyr was a great tip! I will study more about it, thank you very much. Is the Dart html library just for web flutter or does it work for mobile?

Comment: Dart Html library is currently only for web

Comment: I took a look at Zefyr, it seems a little loose, many tutorials outdated, is it really worth using in a project? I couldn't get support for image upload with Zefyr, have you already?

Comment: Depends on the need.. if your purpose is to upload image also then Summer note works well too

Comment: yes, uploading image is in my plans. But summernote is for the web, isn't it? I would like alternatives aimed only at Android / Ios

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_summernote. You can use this package for Mobile Android and Ios